# Android - Resume an application by using Activity.resume() with a callback who has a pointer of target activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, ipc, handler

I have two applications A and B.
Since A and B exchange data by IPC Messenger, I wonder it's ok if I use a Handler handleMessage() event to:
(1) app A is foreground: resume app B (stop stack activity).
(2) app B is foreground: resume app A (stop stack activity).

Now I'm using new intent with ComponentName(packageName, className) to switch between two apps. A and B both have multiple activities, so to resume the top stack activity on the other map, I'm using a message who tell "i'm A, i'm at class A3," so the foreground app B can have the right className to create the launch intent.

Someone have any ideas for me? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't launch an Application, you can only launch activites. So, if you have different Activities on either side, I think your approach is reasonable.

Alternatively you could create a new Activity per application, which is transparent. This activity should then receive all intents and can delegate them to the activity which should really be opened with `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

I honestly don't know which approach is better. I think that's more of a design question: use what you like better.

In general: If you have two apps, both developped by you, which are as deeply linked as you describe, think of merging them into one.